# Is it possible to change the style on a WMS layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms

Apologies from a QGIS beginner but I have added a WMS layer of polygons to fill in the gaps of an existing data set I have. the problem is that I want all of this data to have the same style (colour etc) and the WMS layer which comes up as orange cross hatching doesn't seeem to be able to be modified to a single colour for example. Is it actually possible to change the style of a WMS layer in a way that is possible for beginners?

Answer (score 5):

No.  WMS is a image that is generated and sent from a server.  Once you have it in QGIS it's too late to change it.

Comment: This is partly true, however if you are the publisher of the WMS, then you may change the style from either the map doc, map doc plugin, or style editor.

Comment: Of course.  I was making the assumption that the OP was not the publisher.

Comment: Well, there's limited options to change the colortones - i.e. setting it to grayscales or or blending in a color tone. The kind of styling the OP is asking for however is far out of reach. Depending on the nature of the dataset, one should try get a hold of the shapefile which is served by the WMS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you use GeoServer with [Dynamic Colormap Generation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/colormap/index.html).